# Flowcharts (pie and vertical)

Tags: java, html, css, servlets

I have been searching for some days on internet a way to make flow charts(pie and vertical) using html and css, but I didn't find anything.Did someone make these types of charts in html and css and could help me ?

Finally I found a way to do this charts but I want the values to be the values computed on servlet side.For vertical pie is working but for pie chart no(nothing displayed).Also I want the scale to be at my max value (("${sumC}")=2000),now it is at 60.
Could anyone hep me with thos problems?
Thank you very much!

Here is my servlet code:

```
public class ListaCumparaturi extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
              response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");


              try{
                    ...
                    request.setAttribute("sumG", sumG);
                    request.setAttribute("sumCa", sumCa);
                    request.setAttribute("sumP", sumP);
                    request.setAttribute("sumC", sumC); 

     }
               catch (Exception e2)
               {
                 e2.printStackTrace();
               }
               finally
               {
                 out.close();
               }
            }
}
```

Here is the js code:

```
     <form action= "listacumparaturi" method="get">     
                    <canvas width="1000" height="1000" id="myCanvas"></canvas>


                    var x=  "${sumC}" ; 
            var y= "${sumG}" ; var z= "${sumP}" ; var w=  "${sumCa}" ;   total = "${sumT}";


      var vertical = {
        Calorii: x,
        Grasimi: y,
        Proteine: z,
        Carbo: w
      };
      var data = Object.keys(vertical);


      var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      ctx.fillStyle = "blue";


        total = "${sumT}";



      color = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow','green','black'];
      start = 0;

              for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                ctx.fillRect((i * 60) + 50, 100, 10, -(vertical[data[i]]));
                ctx.font = "9px Arial";
                ctx.fillText(data[i], (i * 60) + 51, 112);
                ctx.fillText((700 * i), 30, ((20 * -i) + 100));

                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(600, 150);
                ctx.arc(600, 150, 150, start, start +
                  (Math.PI * 2 * (vertical[data[i]] / total)), false);
                ctx.lineTo(600, 150);
                ctx.fillStyle = color[i];
                ctx.fill();
                start += Math.PI * 2 * (vertical[data[i]] / total);


              }
    </script>
                    </form>
```

Comment: if you don't have problems with css3 you could use http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree

Comment: There isn't made a pie chart or vertical chart.I don't now how to modify that code to get what I want :(

Comment: you should provide some code to see what HTML you have and what you CSS tried so far ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to build customm charts with HTML and CSS3 canvas.

I have created one sample codepen URL for reference.

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/EyjJLy

You can update your own data and build start charts from there

HTML:

Javascript:

```
      //sample data object

      var vertical = {
        a: 10,
        b: 20,
        c: 40
      };
      var data = Object.keys(vertical);

      total = 0;
      var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        total = total + vertical[data[i]];

      }

      color = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'];
      start = 0;

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        ctx.fillRect((i * 60) + 50, 100, 10, -(vertical[data[i]]));
        ctx.font = "9px Arial";
        ctx.fillText(data[i], (i * 60) + 51, 112);
        ctx.fillText((20 * i), 30, ((20 * -i) + 100));

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(600, 150);
        ctx.arc(600, 150, 150, start, start +
          (Math.PI * 2 * (vertical[data[i]] / total)), false);
        ctx.lineTo(600, 150);
        ctx.fillStyle = color[i];
        ctx.fill();
        start += Math.PI * 2 * (vertical[data[i]] / total);
      }
```

Hope this is helpful for you :)

Comment: Thank you very much it worked! But do you know how can I pass the parameters from servlet as inputs for charts.E.g  for a : (I want the value from servlet). I tried this :  var vertical = {
                  a: ("${sumC}"),
                  b: ("${sumCa}"),
                  c: ("${sumP}")
                };
It worked for vertical but for pie chart is not working (nothing displayed).Do you know also where I should change the value for piechart? Thanks

Comment: Then this should be another question :) ..Paste the code which you are trying ....I will check and tell you

Comment: I have edited my question with the code.Also I want the scale to have my max value (("${sumC}")). Currently my scale stops at 60 and should be (("${sumC}")=2000)

Comment: This step is causing that to stop at 60 ,      ctx.fillText((20 * i), 30, ((20 * -i) + 100));

Replace it with ctx.fillText((700 * i), 30, ((20 * -i) + 100)); for step 700 and max 2100

Comment: It worked, but still have the problem with the pie chart :(

Comment: Could you please provde me sample data ...to test from my side ..Because the sample code which i have provided is not  a dynamic now ....little math is required to make it work perfect..I will check and let you know

Comment: sorry , my code works fine , if you add additional color on adding every new parameter.http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/Meayrb..works fine with four values..Check it once and confirm

Comment: add one more color..it should work now 
color = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow','black'];
different color, i see you are using two green back to back which will not show accurate ...try using different color..Hope this works for you...If so mark it as answered  :)

Comment: SumG,SumCa,SumC,SumP. For this parameters the values are dynamic,the values are computed on the servlet side based on some values from db.Then I pass those parameters to jsp. Some values computed could be: SumC:1080,SumCa:92,SumP:84,SumG:49 . Note that this values are computed dynamic and there wouldn't be the same everytime.

Comment: Did you try steps from my previous comments- adding new color 
"add one more color..it should work now color = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow','black']; different color, i see you are using two green back to back which will not show accurate .."

Comment: Yes added,but still have the problem.No pie chart shown.If I remove  var vertical = {

                    Total_Calorii : ("${sumC}"),
                    Total_Grasimi: ("${sumG}"),
                    Total_Proteine: ("${sumP}"),
                    Total_Carbohidrati: ("${sumCa}")


                  }; 
and put static values it works. But this is not what I want

Comment: could you please share the screenshot with the browser console..if usig google chrome ..use Ctrl+Shift+J and let me know the error

Comment: GET http://localhost:8080/e-health_nutrition/.js/jqplot.pieRenderer.js 
jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js:21 JQMIGRATE: Logging is active
script.js:51 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).superfish is not a function(anonymous function) @ script.js:51c @ jquery.js:3p.fireWith @ jquery.js:3x.extend.ready @ jquery.js:3q @ jquery.js:3
listacumparaturi:69 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).UItoTop is not a function(anonymous function) @ listacumparaturi:69c @ jquery.min.js:3p.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:3b.extend.ready @ jquery.min.js:3H @ jquery.min.js:3

Comment: This error seems to be a backend error , as frontend code works fine ....Can you try to assign those backend values to some variables and try to do console.log or alert those values to check whether they are getting populated or not 
var x= "(${sumC}");
var y=("${sumG}");
var z=("${sumP}");
var w= ("${sumCa}");
alert("x"+x);
alert("y"+y);
alert("z"+z);
alert("w"+w);

Comment: Yes,assigned, the vertical chart works fine,but the problem is at pie chart(doesn't appear).I think that the problem is here :  Total_Calorii : ("${sumC}"),
                    Total_Grasimi: ("${sumG}"),
                    Total_Proteine: ("${sumP}"),
                    Total_Carbohidrati: ("${sumCa}")

Maybe this type of assign is not compatible (("${sumCa}"))

Comment: an you try to assign those backend values to some variables and try to do console.log or alert those values to check whether they are getting populated or not.... var x= "(${sumC}"); var y=("${sumG}"); var z=("${sumP}"); var w= ("${sumCa}"); alert("x"+x); alert("y"+y); alert("z"+z); alert("w"+w);

Comment: increase canvas width and height -
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
 <canvas width="1000" height="1000" id="myCanvas"></canvas>

Comment: Where should I put : var w = window.innerWidth; var h = window.innerHeight;? I increased the values,still have the problem

Comment: sorry ignore those variables

Comment: Could you please try to alert total to check whether it is available or not?

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                    total = total + vertical[data[i]];
alert(total);
                  }

Comment: Yes.Appear 4 popp-up's where are displyed my values passed from servlet and is displayed only one line for vertical chart .

Comment: it should return total sum of those 4 values  at the last alert

Comment: returns me the  values in a string

Comment: Could you please share the output which you are getting?

Comment: At the last alert : 010804984921080498492

Comment: Can try to get total from the Servlet and assign it to total? that will make pie chart to load..for testing you can hard code total and try to see whether it is loading or not.
remove below code
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        total = total + vertical[data[i]];

      }
and repalce total = 2000;

Comment: yes,worked,I have computed the sum in the servlet and passed the value in js, and it worked.Thanks
But I have another problem the pie is not colored as it will be normal.My top value didn't color almost the pie, another color that have a low value color almost the pie. Could you please take a look? I will update my above code.

Comment: Remove it for loop ..no need of for loop
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                total = "${sumT}";

              }.

just keep  total = "${sumT}";

Comment: Removed,but I see that in my vertical chart my first line is that one with blue color instead of read.IN vertical chart i Have : blue-red-blue-yellow, instead of : ref-blue-yellow-green

Comment: Your starting part of code sholud look something like this 
 var x=  "${sumC}" ; 
  var y= "${sumG}" ; 
  var z= "${sumP}" ; 
  var w=  "${sumCa}" ;  
 total = "${sumT}";
              var vertical = {                Calorii: x,                Grasimi: y,                Proteine: z,
                Carbo: w
              };
              var data = Object.keys(vertical);
                var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
              var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
              ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
              color = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow','green','black']

Comment: Is working fine now,the vertical chart is with problem now . because the colors shown are  blue-red-blue-yellow  instead of : ref-blue-yellow-green.
I modyfied as you said

Comment: Add below code in for loop--ctx.fillStyle = color[i];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
               ctx.fillStyle = color[i];
                ctx.fillRect((i * 60) + 50, 100, 10, -(vertical[data[i]]));

Comment: Also the lines are too long.For example my line for Calorii is equal with the line with Carbo, but Calorii = 1080 and Carbo = 92.
Why the difference is too little when should be very big

Comment: you need to adjust x, y coordinates .....ctx.fillRect((i * 60) + 50, 700, 10, -(vertical[data[i]]));

Add this to see the clipped bar......Use w3school html canvas for good reference on adjusting the coordinates

Comment: Thank you ,it worked, also do you know how can I scale it down ? because is filling almost my entire page :(